# Algorithm for finding my position using the distance from 3 different points

Tags: algorithm, position

I'm trying to develop an algorithm for a robot, which takes the distance from three different points which are visible to the robot, assumes each point is a center of a circle, and the distance is a radius of a that circle, and then maps the robot position as the intersection of those 3 circles.

I have difficulties to develop the algorithm, and even a math formula would help. Also, I also have the angle between the robot and each point, but don't know where to use it.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: As per the bulletin on the right, we are no longer using the `homework` tag.

Comment: The points need to be distinct and non-linear or there may be more than one solution.

Comment: The points are distinct, because the robot's sensor is free to chose his points in every step.
About the homework tag - didn't notice that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the three points are not aligned, which you can verify with

```
(y1 - y2)*(x1 - x3) != (y1 - y3)*(x1 - x2)
```

if x1, x2 and x3 are all different; if two of them are equal and the third is not, the three points of course *can't* be aligned and you needn't check.

We can now reduce to a known solution:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110309/three-circle-intersection-for-circles-of-unbounded-integer-radius

Your robot will be in the intersection of the three circles. (Extra characters to allow my 1 character edit to be accepted).

Comment: Believe you have a typo in your cross-product co-linearity test: the test should be (y1 - y2)*(x1 - x3) != (y1 - y3)*(x1 - x2)

Answer (score 0):

Trilateration. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration